# ServerManager under IIS 8

Tags: powershell, iis-8

Moved to windows 8 and I am trying to run the following in powershell

```
# Load the Web Management and Administration Assembly
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Management")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")

$ServerManager = New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
$defaultSite = $ServerManager.Sites["Default Web Site"];
```

The Sites array is empty

Running

```
appcmd.exe list sites
```

gives

```
SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,state:Started)
```

This worked on IIS 7 with windows 7

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just use the [snap-in](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-navigating-the-iis-snap-in-namespace)?

Answer (score 3):

Well lots of trawling through the web produced the following solution

Using

```
$computer = gc env:computername
$ServerManager = [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::OpenRemote($computer.ToLower())
$defaultSite = $ServerManager.Sites["Default Web Site"];
```

Produced the desired result. Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Lifesaver.  I've a build script which works fine locally but failed on the build server.  The .ToLower() was the crux of this.